# Details are missing when exporting from a grouped kendo grid

Tags: excel, telerik, kendo-grid

I'm try to export a kendo grid to excel when data are grouped.
I cannot get the details part.
For example, I'm using the sample provided in the page http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/excel/detail-grid-export

In order to group the data according to the country, I've updated the code with :

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    toolbar: ["excel"],
    dataSource: {
      type: "odata",
      transport: {
        read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
      },
      pageSize: 6,
      group: [{field:"Country"}], // <----- Inserted line
      serverPaging: true
    },
    height: 600,
    pageable: true,
    detailInit: detailInit,
    excel: {
      allPages: true
    },
...
```

I grouped the data according to the country and when I export to Excel, the details are no longer exported.

Did I miss something ?

Thank you.

Comment: Nobody could help me?

Comment: Any idea ? I know it is an old thread, but the question is still "boring" me